# Fix NameError in python

Tags: python

I have created a program to take inputs from the user and find the average of those inputs. My code is -

```
def avg(*a):
    sum = 0
    n = 0
    while 1:
        a = input("enter number :")
        b = a.isdigit()
        if b is False:
            continue
        if int(a) == 0:
            break
        sum += int(a)
        n += 1
    return sum/n

avg()
print("AVG :",avg(a))
```

However, am getting this error -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Metro\Desktop\python\script2.py", line 16, in <module>
    print("AVG :",avg(a))
                      ^
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Comment: You have not defined (or "created") the variable "a" anywhere and trying to access it.

Comment: @rr_goyal `a` is in the local scope of `avg`, but there is no `a` in the global scope which you can use as a variable in the function call `avg`.

Comment: See [link](https://pythonbasics.org/scope/) for some essential guidance on variable scope in Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got NameError because pass variable `a` to func `avg` and this variable not define in global scope and you dont need `break` and `continue`

```py
def avg():
    total = 0
    count = 0
    while True:
        user_input = input("Enter number (for finish enter 0): ")
        if user_input.isdigit():
            num = int(user_input)
            if num == 0:
                return total / count if count != 0 else 0
            total += num
            count += 1

print("Average: ", avg())
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no question in your question...

But the print statement is referencing a variable `a` which has not been defined outside the function.

I think what you're trying to do is this?

```py
def avg():
    sum = 0
    n = 0
    while 1:
        a = input("enter number :")
        b = a.isdigit()
        if b == False:
            continue
        if int(a) == 0:
            return sum / n
            break
        sum += int(a)
        n += 1


print("AVG :", avg())
```

That is:

- Ask the user for input over and over
- If the user inputs "0", stop asking and print the average of all the previously-entered numbers